# How to arrange a replication in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, replication

Here is my problem. I have a busy Drupal site struggling under high load. After applying all caches I see that, no surprisingly,  database is the bottleneck. I have two servers to handle the site: A and B, on the same rack/subnet. The server A is frontend web server and is set to handles all database queries to the server B. Currently there is no detabase set up on A. The database on B is MariaDB 10. CPU-wise, The server A is much less powerful than B, but has the same amount of RAM. The load on server A is very low (< 0.5) The load on server B is not low (> 5)

So my questions are:

-Are there any benefit in defining master/slave database on these two servers?

-If is good idea to go master/slave route, how do you arrange the servers? (which server should be the master? Which one should be the frontend?)

Comment: Did you already analyze the cause of the slowness on the DB? Is it I/O, CPU, slow queries?. Also what kind of tuning did you do on the DB?

Comment: Well there are plenty of expensive queries which produce +2500qps. I did optimize database and indexed it as much as I could throughout the time and I don't think I can get more of a single database. So wondering why not blend in the computational power of server A to handle some queries.

Comment: What about duplicate the Apache in B and have MySQL master/master on both servers. Then a load balancer in front of the Apaches

Comment: I'm open to all arrangements that may give the best performance. As for master/master, not sure how it could be better in my scenario when two servers specs are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

It should have benefit by setting up slave database on server A. Server A has a lower loading and it would has less network overhead from the frontend to the slave database.

Server B should be used as the master database as it has more resource/power. However, Server B could be serve as a slave database with the same instance as well. By defining both server A and B as slaves, loading from select queries can be shared between server A and B.

Reference on setting up multiple slaves,
https://drupal.org/node/310071

Comment: Which server should be the front-end in this arrangment? Thanks

Comment: Server A because Drupal's also consume CPU power.